# How can I make psql command to work properly on my mac terminal

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql

I have installed PostgreSql on my mac. Everything seems to work fine since I am able to use the backslash to show some Postgres commands. But when I am trying with the command line 'psql --help' it seems to do nothing. Some advice will be very helpful!, Also I will add an image of my terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing there are command line options, ie they only work outside of the interactive psql shell. Your only options here are really `\help` or `\?`.